# How to fix Dynamic cell height problem in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview, cell

I have a cell in xib and I'm trying to make the cell dynamic.
I want the cell to resize when my label is multilined.

When I put in these 2 lines of code it work when my label is multilined:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60
```

The problem is, when my label is not multilined it is now about row height 100 as standard, while 60 was the standard before putting these 2 lines in, and it looked just like it should with 60 and everything fits perfectly, with 100 it's a lot of dead space.

In my cell I have a view, inside that view I have 2 buttons, 1 view that works like an image for animation, 1 stack view that contains[1 label, 1 button], here comes a picture of it.

[XibCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRlvK.png)

I've checked a lot of guides and questions here on stacked, but I can't make it work.

"Update"

I've figured out that it has something todo with the constraints on the stack view or the stackView items. If you look at the picture I posted, the button with time and a label over it is in a stack view, that stack view is constrained bottom, leading, trailing and top.

The label in stack view  is constraint leading, top and bot
The button in stack view is constraint bot, top, leading. I've tried a lot of different standard combinations with the constraints inside.

Comment: It would help if you provide a sample Xcode project for the issue or at least the .xib file

Comment: I've figured out that it has something todo with the constraints on the stack view or the stackView items. If you look at the picture I posted, the button with time and a label over it is in a stack view, that stack view is constrained bottom, leading, trailing and top. 

The label in stack view  is constraint leading, top and bot
The button in stack view is constraint bot, top, leading. I've tried a lot of different standard combinations with the constraints inside.